# Entity Framework 6 Lazy Loading and Querying Navigation Properties

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

**Trigger Warning:** I am a former NHibernate user making the switch over to EF.

Just ran into my first major disappointment with Entity Framework 6. In [this abstract base class](https://gist.github.com/NotMyself/b9e782143cf6f7ca5e56), I have the basic functionality for an account.

An account has a collection of transactions. To determine the available balance of an account, I simply subtract the total expenses and non released encumbrances from the total deposits. This is pure business logic related to all types of accounts.

To get total amounts, I have a handful of properties that filter the account's transactions by type and sums the amount on the transactions. See [TotalDepositAmount](https://gist.github.com/NotMyself/b9e782143cf6f7ca5e56#file-account-cs-L18) for an example of a couple ways I tried to do this.

I am using Lazy Loading in EF and what I expected EF to do was issue a query to the database to get the summed value of the deposit transactions. Instead, EF fetches ALL the transactions for the account and loads them into memory and then linq filters them. WTF.

I only found this issue because I was doing some performance testing in my sample application and pumped 30k transactions (a totally possible amount) into an account. Attempting to ToString my account basically crashes the app now...

After digging around, I discovered that the only way to query a navigation property is to do it when you fetch the parent or have access to the dbcontext inside your entity.. so the property would look something like this..

```
public decimal TotalDepositAmount
{
    get
    {
        return context.Entry(this).Reference("Transactions").Query()
            .OfType<Deposit>().Sum(d => d.Amount);
    }
}
```

But of course, I don't have access to the context inside my entity and having it would completely pollute the purity of my entities...

So, EF experts. What am I missing. How can I accomplish my goal here of having pure domain entities. What work arounds or patterns can I use?

Comment: Did you find a solution to your problem yet?

Comment: I am also looking for solution. Your provided example can't be used in querying and filtering by that property.

Answer (score 0):

This is assuming that your base class Transactions has a property that is a list of Deposits

```
context.Transactions.Where(x => x.Deposit.Count > 1).Sum(d => d.Amount);
```

I tested this using

```
db.Database.Log = s => System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"SQL: {s}");
```

and placed it before the line above. If you look in your output you should see that the transactions are being limited by a where clause in the subselect.